# Check running installation in C#

Tags: c#, windows-installer, installation

Is there a way to determine if there is an active installation running in C#? For example, some times if you launch 2 MSIs (or setup.exes) at once one of them will say that there is already installation going on in progress. Is there a way to do that in C#? Say, a self-resetting registry key (that system resets) or a mutex?

Comment: You might be able to use the MSI APIs to do this.  If you don't, then there's no guarantee your registry/mutex hack won't break.  I believe the cleanest wrapper for the Windows installer APIs is available at: http://wix.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: There might be a call in the MSI API that does it, but I didn't find it. Perhaps one can check `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer : InProgress` to determine if there is an active installation in progress? (not tested)

Answer (score 1):

A mutex is the way to go.

```
bool isFirst;
Mutex m = new Mutex(false, "MyMutex", out isFirst);
```

If isFirst is false then there is another process running. As for the name if you want this to check across multiple sessions (terminal sessions) then change the code to something like.

```
Mutex m = new Mutex(false, "Global\\MyMutex", out isFirst);
```

Comment: right, but what if I want to also see if windows installer is running?